# remove successive rows in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

What is efficient way to remove successive row with duplicate values in specific fields in hive? for example:

Input:

```
 ID field1  field2 date
 1   a       b     2015-01-01
 1   a       b     2015-01-02
 2   e       d     2015-01-03
```

output:

```
ID field1  field2 date
 1   a       b     2015-01-01
 2   e       d     2015-01-03
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove successive duplicates is to use `lag` to check the previous `id` and only keep rows where the previous `id` is different:

```
select * from (
    select * , 
        lag(id) over (order by date) previous_id
    from mytable
) t where t.previous_id <> t.id 
or t.previous_id is null -- accounts for the 1st row
```

If you also need to check `field1` and `field2`, then you can add separate `lag` statements for each field:

```
select * from (
    select * , 
        lag(id) over (order by date) previous_id,
        lag(field1) over (order by date) previous_field1
    from mytable
) t where (t.previous_id <> t.id and t.previous_field1 <> field1)
or t.previous_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Fuzzy Tree..this method works..:)

Comment: @user2895589 glad it helped